# I have a table generated from json data and I want to extract the id of multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ruby, json

Using ruby, sinatra and postgres I have generated a table,using a getJSON call, as follows:

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="case" id=" + this["id"] + "> etc.
```

Now I want to be able to extract the id of the checked checkboxes and it is proving troublesome.

None of the approaches below work and the id is always "undefined". I need to collect ids and then bung them into the database along with something else. The jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".add").click(function() {
alert("clicked");
//$(".content").delegate('tr > td:first-child > input:checked').each(function() {
$(".content").delegate('.case').each(function() {
                //var id = $(".content").delegate('tr > td:first-child > input:checked').val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                alert('this is the id: ' + id);
             });
     });
});
```

What would you recommend? Many thanks.

Comment: i think `id=" + this["id"] + "` this must be `id=" + this['id'] + "` **or** `id=" + this["+id+"] + "`

Comment: Thank you. That part is correct, I just slightly simplified it to put it here on stack. There is no mistake and the id is present.

Comment: in fact it's: '<td style=\"background:#E3F6CE;\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"case\" id=\"' + this["id"] + '\">'; which is OK.

Comment: have you given up on me Dipesh?

Comment: i never give up dude...but its not clear to me.? can you please create fiddle for this.?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to "create a fiddle". The json table works fine and the elements display correctly. I want to reference the id value of the checked item so that I can then (with ajax) put it into my database. Content is the parent div into which the table is rendered. Still unclear? I can send you the files if you like but without the database data you may not easily be able to replicate it. Link here: http://richtalent.herokuapp.com/cuse

Comment: link is not working.....

Comment: okay got html i am creating fiddle with solution okay..

Comment: what happens is:1. filter by industry then country
2. get names
3. check names
4. select shortlist and "add"

Comment: problem is in same id for more than one dom....you have similar id `id="case"` for each checkbox that is causing the error

Comment: then we can use value instead of id?

Comment: Yes you can user any custom attribute in `html5`. do that and try

Comment: where is the filddle?

Comment: I have already tried with value and I get a blank alert so it's not being captured.

Comment: can you please paste code at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: OK pasted. Do I need to open an account with them to save it? so you can access t?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HGgy3/

Comment: OK, have you got the fiddle link?